# issue with while/case statement in linux scripting

Tags: linux, shell, unix

In my script I have while loop with case statement its working fine, I have added two more arguments as input to script. So i have added 2 cases in the existing case statement.

-a and -d are newly added blocks.

Am passing the arguments for the same as below.

```
test.sh -s NY -t N -f DLY -a 20151022 -d 4
```

But the same is not getting evaluated. -s, -t and -f are evaluating fine.

Do i need to do something for adding new cases in existing case statement, For any case if it would be issue with spaces how to resolve it. Spent my full day time but no clue.

Appreciate your responses, Thanks in advance. Below is the code snippet.

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
case ${1} in
--Src|-s
    IN_SRC=$(echo {2} | tr [a-z] [A-Z])
    shift;;
--type|-t
    IN_TYPE=$(echo {2} | tr [a-z] [A-Z])
    shift;;
--fre|-f
    IN_FRE=$(echo {2} | tr [a-z] [A-Z])
    shift;;
--asofd|-a
    IN_DATE=$(echo {2} | tr [a-z] [A-Z])
    shift;;
--DayWk|-d
    IN_DAYWK=$(echo {2} | tr [a-z] [A-Z])
    shift;;
-*)
    echo"Error log details"
;;
*) break;;
esac
shift
done
```

Comment: there are some syntax errors, ie no right parenthesis after case values, `{2}` instead if `${2}`.

Comment: earlier scirpt has type errors, corrected the syntax errors.

Comment: I would expect that, given the above code, none of the options are working at all, because there are enough syntax errors that `bash` (or most any other shell that I'm aware of, for that matter) will simply abort trying to parse it. Post the actual code that you are having issues with, and we might be able to spot an error, but the above code has a number of other errors that are probably hiding your original issue...

Answer (score 0):

Not

```
$(echo {2} | tr [a-z] [A-Z])
```

but

```
$(echo "$2" | tr [a-z] [A-Z])
# .....^^^^
```

You need to actually expand the variable. Otherwise, you just getting the literal string `{2}`

Also missing the parentheses on your case branches.

I'd strongly recommend using `getopts` instead of re-inventing this particular wheel. If you need the long options, use `getopt`. Example:

```
declare -u in_src in_type in_fre in_date in_daywk

while getopt s:t:f:a:d: opt; do
    case $opt in
        s) in_src=$OPTARG ;;
        t) in_type=$OPTARG ;;
        f) in_fre=$OPTARG ;;
        a) in_date=$OPTARG ;;
        d) in_daywk=$OPTARG ;;
        :) echo "Error: missing argument for -$OPTARG" >&2; exit 1 ;;
        ?) echo "Error: unknown option: -$OPTARG" >&2; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))
```